# How to make NVDA screen reader read the aria-label?

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

Screen reader not reading this div:

```
<div tabindex="7" aria-label="Here be redundant or extraneous content" >
```

It should read "Here be redundant or extraneous content"

Any help how to solve this problem with HTML?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Use of positive values for `tabindex` is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

A `div` is neither landmark nor interactive content. An `aria-label` will not be read by a screen reader (and rightly so).

Use an off-screen technique:

```
<div class="sr-only">
Here be redundant or extraneous content
</div>
```

The CSS might look like this (accounting for RTL languages too):

```
.SRonly {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  top: auto;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

html[dir=rtl] .SRonly {
  left: inherit;
  left: unset;
  right: -9999px;
}
```

[There are other techniques](http://hugogiraudel.com/2016/10/13/css-hide-and-seek/), but their value depends on your audience and its technology profile.

Further, [never use a positive `tabindex` value](http://adrianroselli.com/2014/11/dont-use-tabindex-greater-than-0.html). And [never use a `div` as interactive content](http://adrianroselli.com/2016/01/links-buttons-submits-and-divs-oh-hell.html) (which the tab-stop implies is your intent).

In the future, your question might get more attention if you provide an example and description of the challenge you are trying to solve.